# How do I map database columns to a struct in a list of structs in Racket?

Tags: odbc, racket

I have a list called attendance-events, consisting of struct type attendance-event. The struct is defined as

```
(define-struct attendance-event (date flag))
```

The "date" is the date of the event and "flag" is a 2 character value that represents the type of event.

In my database, I am selecting "select date, code from attendance_table", and I want those two columns to be added to the list of attendance-events for each row.

So, how can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean th estruct is defined as `(struct attendance-event (date flag))`?

Comment: Yes, I mean (define-struct attendance-event (date flag))

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This performs the query and returns a list of `attendance-event` structures:

```
(for/list ([(date code)
            (in-query conn "select date, code from attendance_table")])
  (make-attendance-event date code))
```

Comment: Ahhh...so I need a little factory(a function( at the end of the function to actually build the event, correct?

Comment: How do I get the attendance-event list items into the attendance-events list?

Comment: I made the receiving attendance-events list into a gen:stream sequence by giving it the empty?, first and last methods. So the data from the loop goes directly into the attendance-events list as attendance-events.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much easier to work with database rows after they've been converted to hash tables. The following function converts the `rows-result` type returned by the `query` function into a list of immutable hashes:

```
(require (planet jphelps/loop)) ;; Use the loop macro from Common Lisp.

(define (rows-result->hash results)
  (let ((header (rows-result-headers results)))
    (loop for row in (rows-result-rows results)
          collect (loop for ((_ . name) (_ . decltype)) in header
                        for column across row
                        with-collection-type hash/immutable
                        collect (cons name column)))))
```

Then you can wrap the `query` function like this:

```
(define (simple-query query-text conn . params)
  (rows-result->hash (apply query (list* conn query-text params))))
```

Finally, to create your struct:

```
(loop for row in (simple-query "select date,code from attendance_table;")
      collect (make-attendance-event (hash-ref row 'date) (hash-ref row 'code)))
```